# Installing boost.log (windows 7 using codeblocks 12.11+gcc 4.7.1)

Tags: windows, boost, installation, codeblocks, boost-log

I am trying to build and run the Boost.Log library on CodeBlocks 12.11. I have no experience with boost and boost.log, and want to learn it, so, firstly I need to install it.

### Installing boost

First I followed steps on [how to install boost using codeblocks](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=BoostWindowsQuickRef)

As result on two different computers (both has windows 7) I got different list of files in %mypath%\boost\lib
(at one computer there was just 6 files, on another 52)

Bigger list is:

- libboost_chrono-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_chrono-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_date_time-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_date_time-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_exception-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_exception-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_filesystem-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_filesystem-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_graph-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_graph-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_iostreams-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_iostreams-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_locale-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_locale-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_math_c99-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_math_c99-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_math_c99f-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_math_c99f-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_math_c99l-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_math_c99l-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_math_tr1-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_math_tr1-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_math_tr1f-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_math_tr1f-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_math_tr1l-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_math_tr1l-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_program_options-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_program_options-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_random-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_random-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_regex-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_regex-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_serialization-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_serialization-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_signals-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_signals-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_system-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_system-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_test_exec_monitor-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_test_exec_monitor-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_thread-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_thread-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_timer-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_timer-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_unit_test_framework-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_unit_test_framework-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_wave-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_wave-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a
- libboost_wserialization-mgw47-mt-1_52.a
- libboost_wserialization-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a

It was installed with bjam message:

```
...failed updating 10 targets...
...skipped 16 targets...
...updated 764 targets...
```

Is that list full, or my installing of boost missed some libraries?
Why two different computers could give different result of the same actions (I followed same steps from link two times)?
(Comp with just 6 result libs had no VC2010, comp with 52 libs had VC2010, may that be reason?)

### Installing boost.log

Then, on machine with 52 libs, I started to install boost.log following steps from [how to install boost.log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html)

And got two additional libs:

- libboost_log_setup-mgw47-mt-1_52.a (size 22733 kb)
- libboost_log_setup-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a (size 74933 kb)

with next result message from bjam:

```
...failed updating 6 targets...
...skipped 10 targets...
...updated 225 targets...
```

Then I took sample from boost.log distr.:

```
#include <iostream>

//#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/formatters.hpp>
#include <boost/log/filters.hpp>

#include <boost/log/utility/init/to_file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/init/to_console.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/init/common_attributes.hpp>

#include <boost/log/attributes/timer.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace fmt = boost::log::formatters;
namespace flt = boost::log::filters;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace attrs = boost::log::attributes;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

using boost::shared_ptr;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    logging::init_log_to_console(std::clog, keywords::format = "%TimeStamp%: %_%");
    logging::add_common_attributes();
    src::logger lg;
    BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Added libs to project (and path to included files):
also libboost_log_setup-mgw47-mt-d-1_52.a

but while compiling I get errors on:

```
obj\Debug\main.o||In function 'ZN5boost10log_mt_nt57sources12basic_loggerIcNS1_6loggerENS1_19single_thread_modelEED2Ev':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\include\boost-1_52\boost\log\sources\basic_logger.hpp|88|undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_nt5::basic_attribute_set<char>::~basic_attribute_set()'|
```

And don't know how to solve them.

Please, explain me (if possible):

- How can I know that my boost compilation/installation was full and what to do, if that is not (I'm sure installation that gave me 6 libs was not full, but I don't know what to do with it)?
- How can I know that my boost.log compilation was full?
- I read that I have to build boost.lib as shared object, but libs was in subdirectory "link-static", despite command runtime-link=shared for bjam. Should I do something with that?
- What should I do with error I got?

Thank you for help.

Comment: I tried example for boost thread using and got same "undefined reference" problem. So I decide that my boost build was wrong.

From http://nuwen.net/mingw.html I downloaded gcc 4.7.2 with already installed boost (it has 26 libraries, so my compilation with 52 (one release, one debug) was correct).

And I copied that new MinGW directory over existing insode CodeBlocks. And again tried boost thread example. And AGAIN got that "undefined reference" error! =(

Why now? 

I found that may happen if there is no linking to the C runtime library.
May that be problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you have the log-library in the list you applied above.
Undefined reference means that your linker can't find any suitable function in all the libraries you supplied.

Soounds like you missed building the boost log library and you also got a message from the linker unable to find the library.